# Text flow out of divs in chrome, but not on all chrome users?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I got a really strange problem, and after so much tries and research I can't get out of it.
I have a website, but SOME (just 5% of visitors) people with the SAME version of chrome, see the text flowing out of `divs` and text overlapping. It's very strange because I tested the website on all chrome browsers using browser testers, without any problem. And in internet explorer or `firefox` this problem never happens...

A page is located [here](http://maximebossens.be/test/gallery.php)

And here are some screenshots of what SOME people see (maybe you won't see this in chrome)
[click here](http://imageshack.us/g/694/sc2dz.png/)

Maybe it is because of the font face I am using? Or maybe some bad coded CSS?

Please help me out of this!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Broken on my Chrome too, that's all I got for you. Same as screen shots  (left top menu text is shifted right, bottom text overlaps other)

Comment: Really strange, in my chrome (and in multiple others) it looks like this: http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/3079/scrd.png

And with some people it always worked, and suddenly it becomes bad (and stays)

Comment: On which chrome version did you test? (Looks fine on 25.0.1364.5)

Comment: You haven't put your content in 'span' tags. written bad css.

Comment: I tested it also on 23, 25, etc. I tested it on all versions using browserstack.com, adobe browserlab, on all my computers with chrome. Never problems. But some people, with the SAME chrome version (so also latest updated version) get this problem...

Comment: @surinder in the screenshots, the titles which are overlapping (also in footer), they are in span tags.. The menu isn't but that should be a problem because the right menu is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you use `.svg` font. Recently I was hunting some Chrome font rendering bugs and saw this:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95102

This seem very similar to issues you are having. You could try to serve some other font type to Chrome and if this would fix that.

If you don't want or can't serve some other font type to Chrome, the only thing you can do is wait until Chrome version 24 is out to all users which should be soon (I can't find any announcement)

I tested it in

- Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m
- Chrome 26.0.1371.0 canary
- Chromium 25.0.1334.0 (169326)

@ Windows 7 x64 and your page seems fine for me.

Comment: That looks like the same problem! But then there is the other problem that chrome only works with svg fonts? I had another problem a time a go, that the svg font had to be declared first in de @font face css to work in chrome. If I place it 2nd, or further, the font doesn't work in chrome..

Comment: So what options do you propose to fix this? You found any during your hunt?

Comment: I was hunting down some other bugs, not exactly this.
I can confirm this bug *sometimes* occurs on my other PC with same OS and browser version Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m, and that this issue is fixed in Chrome Canary (26.0.1372.0). Chrome stable on the left and Chrome Canary on the right http://i.imgur.com/2dbfc.png

Comment: As for the solution, can you try with some other font? It could be this specific font triggers some Chrome bug. If that is not an option, can you remove svg line from your css for this specific font?
If that doesn't help and if your text is not dynamic. You could set display:inline-block; and specific width (eg. 70px for span with text SEARCH), just as temporary fix until fixed version of Chrome does not come out.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! I will try it out. I generated the fonts using fontsquirrel, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It's Chrome specific, so I think no. Font Squirrel is okay. Please consider accepting my answer. Good luck with this!